# How to properly discretize and solve the Liouville equation?

Tags: computational-physics, probability, differential-equations, discrete

Consider some dynamical system $\dot{\textbf{X}}(\textbf{x},t)=F(\textbf{X})$ where $\textbf{X}$ is discretized along a 1-dimensional spatial coordinate $\textbf{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_N)^T$. Let $\rho(\textbf{X},t)$ be the probability density function, then the Liouville equation describes the evolution of $\rho(\textbf{X},t)$ given by,

‎$\begin{align}‎
‎\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=‎-\sum_{j=0}^{N}\frac{\partial}{\partial X_j}‎‎(F(\textbf{X})\rho(\textbf{X},t))
\end{align}‎$

Here is where I may be confusing myself. If we want to solve this numerically then we need to discretize the phase space. To do this I will assume that each $X_j \in \mathbb{R}^L$. This means that $\rho$ is a lattice in an ultra-high dimensional phase space of size $L^N$ since there are $N$ dimensions each on a lattice of size $L$. The Liouville equation is therefore out of reach to solve numerically for even modestly sized spatial grids.

My question is, am I thinking about this correctly? I spoke to someone who said that I am double discretizing, which is a mistake. However, this is the way that I see the problem so I am looking for either a verification of this method or for someone to point out how I am making an error.

Comment: You should discretize only space & time. If $\rho$ is a function of both space & time, then $\rho(\mathbf{x},\,t)\to\rho_{i,j,k}^n\equiv\rho\left(\mathbf{x}_{i,j,k},\,t^n\right)$.

Comment: In that case, I struggle to understand what $\rho(\textbf{x}_{i,j,k},t^n)$ represents physically. For each time and at each grid cell, it is the probability of what exactly? In the case I outline above, when you discretize the phase space $X_j$ then $\rho(\textbf{X}) \rightarrow \rho(X_j^n)$ and it represents the probability that $X_j$ takes on a specific value at a spatial grid point in time.

Comment: What does $\rho(\mathbf{x},\,t)$ represent physically when you have a specific location & time (e.g., $x=\{3,5,-10\}$ and $t=2$)? Isn't this the same exact thing as when specifying a discretized spacetime? Or if you think it different, what do you perceive as different?

Comment: Here is how I am thinking about it. Suppose that the spatially discretized state vector $X_j^n=X(x_j,t^n)$ represents a temperature. Then $\rho(X_j^n)$ represents the probability that $X_j^n$ is equal to each value in the discretized phase space (e.g. ${10^{\circ}C, 10.1^{\circ}C, 10.2^{\circ}C, \dots}$). If you don't discretize the phase space then how do you assign probabilities to each of the possible state vector values?